# AngularJS. Executing long-running tasks

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Does AngularJS has some mechanism for executing long-running tasks? For example GWT has feature like this:

> Sometimes you want to break up your logic loop so that the JavaScript
>   event loop gets a chance to run between two pieces of code. The
>   Scheduler class in GWT will allow you to do that. The logic that you
>   pass to Scheduler will run at some point in the future, after control
>   has been returned to the JavaScript event loop. This little delay may
>   give the interface a chance to process some user events or initialize
>   other code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript you do this by forcing asynchronous execution of code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    // ... code executed at some later point in time
}, 0);    // timeout of `0` means it will get executed as soon as possible
```

In AngularJS, you'd do this with the `$timeout` service, which is then easily mocked in unit-tests.

---

To give you a full-fledged example:

```
var maxIterations = 100000;
(function brokenUpFn (i) {
    if (i >= maxIterations) {
        return;
    }

    do {
        // ... (some computation-intensive code here)
        i++;
    } while (i % 100);

    setTimeout(brokenUpFn, 0, i);
})(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript historically suffers from an important limitation: all its execution process remains inside a unique thread.

You can try simulate parallel tasks using `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` methods. HTTP requests can also be done in an asynchronous manner, thanks to the `XMLHttpRequest` object that avoids freezing the UI while loading resources from remote servers.

The [Web Workers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#workers) APIs define a way to run script in the background. You can then execute some tasks in threads living outside the main page.

Take a look at this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) and this [example](http://html5demos.com/worker)
Be aware that only new browsers [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=webworkers) this feature