# My loading component just show after end task in angular

Tags: angular

I have a loading component very simple with a subscriber that notify my page to be showed, so this is my component:

**loading.component.html**

```
<div id="loading-wrapper" *ngIf="loading">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

**loading.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {LoadingService} from "./loading.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.css']
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  loading: boolean = false;
  loadingSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingSubscription = this.loadingService.loadingStatus.subscribe((value) => {
      this.loading = value;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.loadingSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }


}
```

So, my component is notified when some change is made in service and show a loading screen. This works very well but i have a case that loading screen is loaded only in end of task. I have another component and in ngOnInit i call :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.startLoading();
  makeSomeLongTask();
  }
```

The `makeSomeLongTask()` is executed and after all execution the loadingScreen appear. How can i solve that ?

**Edit 1**
This is my service class to load component:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  private _loading: boolean = false;
  loadingStatus: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  get loading(): boolean {
    return this._loading;
  }

  set loading(value: boolean) {
    this._loading = value;
    this.loadingStatus.next(value);
  }

  startLoading() {
    this.loading = true;
  }

  stopLoading() {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION**

I solved my problem creating a HTTP Interceptor to show the load screen, see, following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@zeljkoradic/loader-bar-on-every-http-request-in-angular-6-60d8572a21a9

Comment: So, in this case, the loading screen isn't showing after you have said for it to show and then, only after `makeSomeLongTask` has finished does it show. Yet, surely you would have code that says *not* to show the loading once the task is complete. Is it possible that you have a boolean inverted somewhere?

Comment: Unhappy no, my loading-screen is ok, but just show after end of task. I don't know why.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, but you could try wrapping `makeSomeLongTask` in a timeout: `window.setTimeout(() => makeSomeLongTask(), 0)`

Comment: why use timeout 0 ? no make sense

Comment: When you use a timeout, it moves whatever code is within it to the bottom of the execution stack. Which means that if it has any blocking code, which might be stopping the loading screen from showing, it should happen after everything currently queued happens.

Comment: i tried but didnt solve

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas, please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
How are your components used in the layout, especially the loading component and the one with the makeSomeLongTask() method?
What is the implementation of the startLoading() method?

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas can you show the code from LoadingService file, it can be helpful for debugging purpose.

Comment: I edited the post with service code

Answer (score 0):

This behavior happens because change detection is not running through your loading components.

A very easy solution for your problem is to you use the powerful `async` operator provided by angular itself in your template like this:

```
<div id="loading-wrapper" *ngIf="loadingObs | async">
  <div id="loader"></div>
</div>
```

For now you don't have to subscribe to your loading observable because  the async pipe is  handling everything for you (incl. also ChangeDetection).

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, OnInit} from 
'@angular/core';
import {LoadingService} from "./loading.service";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loading',
  templateUrl: './loading.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading.component.css']
})
export class LoadingComponent implements OnInit, 
OnDestroy {


  loadingObs: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingObs = 
this.loadingService.loadingStatus;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two options:

1) Create a webservice for executing the logic inside the `makeSomeLongTask()`

2) Use the [Service workers](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro).

**Disclaimer:**

see [prerequisites](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro#prerequisites) from the link above

> Your application must run in a web browser that supports service
>   workers. Currently, service workers are supported in the latest
>   versions of Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari, Opera, UC Browser (Android
>   version) and Samsung Internet. Browsers like IE and Opera Mini do not
>   provide the support. To learn more about other browsers that are
>   service worker ready, see the Can I Use page and MDN docs

**Disclaimer[2]:**

I haven't used the Service workers on my own in Angular application but it looks like one of the options.

**EDIT**
... there is a third option (which **I would not recommend**), mentioned by [Simon K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5487673/simon-k) in the comments:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    setTimeout(function () {
        makeSomeLongTask();
    }, 0);
}
```

Just try tu run it in other [lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks). Implement the `AfterViewInit`

Comment: Why is so difficult just insert a load screen in angular project ? I think this is a normal practice not?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Why is it so difficult? I think [this  post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127545/4880379) provides a good answer for this question